# Minify code for same divs for same effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, minify

i have the following jquery code:

```
$('#menu1').click(function(e){
    $('#menu1').addClass('fullscreen');
        if($('#menu1').hasClass('fullscreen')){
            $('.barra').removeClass('hidden');
        }
});

$('#close').click(function(e){
    $('#menu1').removeClass('fullscreen').animate({
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px'
    }, 2500); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <div class="content">
            <div id="menu1">
                <div class="blackbar hidden">
                    <a href="" id="close" title="Close"><img src="img/cross.png"     width="40" height="40" alt="fechar"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="menu2">
                <!-- quadrado 2 -->
            </div>

            <div id="menu3">
                <!-- quadrado 3 -->
            </div>

            <div id="menu4">
                <!-- quadrado 4 -->
            </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I want the same for all divs, called "menu" (from 1 to 4), without having to copy the same code and having too many lines, for the same procedure.

All div's will have "$('#menu').addClass('fullscreen');" and "$('.barra').removeClass('hidden');". Any help or guidance?

How to achieve this?

**CSS**

```
section{ //"menu" alignment center
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.content{ 
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 420px; 
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 9%;
}

#menu1, #menu2, #menu3, #menu4{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

#menu1.fullscreen{
    top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 9;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
    background: #131313;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: you can use a `.each()` loop on the menu divs if you dont have any requirement for the numbers (1,2,3...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this by using a class selector.
Add a class "menu" to echo menu element:

```
<div id="menu2" class="menu">
    <!-- quadrado 2 -->
</div>
```

Then Select it like so:

```
$('.menu').click(function(e){
    $(this).addClass('fullscreen');
        if($(this).hasClass('fullscreen')){
            $('.barra').removeClass('hidden');
        }
});
```

The jQuery selector `$(this)` refers to the clicked element.

Comment: Store a reference to `this` vs querying it each time, `$this = $(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just finished your code, I improved it a bit by adding one or two things. So here it goes .. while you did not provide a css or anything I styled it fast to be able to get the job done.

**CSS**

```
    <style>
        div[id^="menu"]{
            background: #333;
            margin: 30px;
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 80px;
        }
        .close {
            display: none;
            color: #fff;
            width: 100%;
            height: 15px;
            background: #4779ff;
        }

        .ThisElementIsClicked .close {
            display: block;
        }
  </style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
            <div id="menu1" class="menu-box">
                <div class="blackbar hidden">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="close" title="Close"><img src="img/cross.png" width="40" height="40" alt="fechar"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="menu2" class="menu-box">
               <div class="blackbar hidden">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="close" title="Close"><img src="img/cross.png" width="40" height="40" alt="fechar"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="menu3" class="menu-box">
                <div class="blackbar hidden">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="close" title="Close"><img src="img/cross.png" width="40" height="40" alt="fechar"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="menu4" class="menu-box">
                <div class="blackbar hidden">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="close" title="Close"><img src="img/cross.png" width="40" height="40" alt="fechar"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery WITH COMMENTS** - go below for the no comments version

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        //focus on all elements that have an ID starting with the string 'menu'
        //you do that adding '^' before the '=' sign.
        var targetThis = $('div[id^="menu"]');

        //test it yourself to see it's working
        //uncomment this line below to display the info into your console
        //console.log(targetThis);

        targetThis.on('click', function(){

            //set a variable with the element you clicked on
            var thisEl = $(this),
                thisID = thisEl.attr('id').substr(4);

            if(!thisEl.hasClass('ThisElementIsClicked'))
            {
                //if you want all other menu boxes to close while
                //the current clicked menu box is clicked just remove the class for
                //all elements that have the ID starting with the string 'menu'
                //that is the first variable we created before the click event occured
                //uncomment the line below to see the results

                //targetThis.removeClass('ThisElementIsClicked');

                //add the class to the current clicked menu box
                thisEl.addClass('ThisElementIsClicked');

                //remove the hidden class
                //but this should not be made with jQuery but with CSS
                //just style the 'hidden' class based on the parent class that we added on click 'ThisElementIsClicked'
                $('#menu' + thisID).children('.blackbar').removeClass('hidden');

                //now while this box is opened
                //add inside this block of code the script for
                //the closing button
                var closeBtn = thisEl.find('.close');

                closeBtn.on('click', function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $(this).parents('#menu' + thisID).removeClass('ThisElementIsClicked');
                    $(this).parents('#menu' + thisID).children('.blackbar').addClass('hidden');
                });


            }

        });

    });
```

**jQuery NO COMMENTS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var targetThis = $('div[id^="menu"]');

        targetThis.on('click', function(){

            var thisEl = $(this),
                thisID = thisEl.attr('id').substr(4);

            if(!thisEl.hasClass('ThisElementIsClicked'))
            {
                //targetThis.removeClass('ThisElementIsClicked');
                thisEl.addClass('ThisElementIsClicked');
                $('#menu' + thisID).children('.blackbar').removeClass('hidden');
                var closeBtn = thisEl.find('.close');

                closeBtn.on('click', function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $(this).parents('#menu' + thisID).removeClass('ThisElementIsClicked');
                    $(this).parents('#menu' + thisID).children('.blackbar').addClass('hidden');
                });

            }

        });

    });
```

Hope this helps you ... and by the way, you have the option to only display one box at the time, when you click a box all other boxes close. Read the comments.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I tried the code but, the "close" button just appeared on the created boxes.

Comment: Ps: I added the CSS I had at the time, the goal is to make each menu div box, expand to become full screen.

Comment: What do you mean the close btn 'just appeared' ? The code does exactly what you want (if I understood correctly) ... is up to you to add the right CSS. Try copying all I've posted into a new .html file and run it .. but make sure you load jQuery first.

Comment: Lol .. I just tried now and it seems that editor doesn't work .. create a new file on your computer don't use that browser editor, create test.html .. copy the CSS with the <style> tag into the <head> tag .. the HTML inside the <body> the scripts at the bottom, make sure jquery.js is the first loaded script ... and it works .. I wrote that code in my editor and does exactly what you want :)